# Use pip with Python 3.5

Tags: python, pip

I have a AWS Ubuntu instance where I manually installed Python3.5 (downloaded it, configured, and ran make, make install). Then I changed the symbolic link

```
sudo ln -fs /opt/python3.5/bin/python3.5 /usr/bin/python3
```

But then when I try to run pip:

```
ubuntu@xxx:/dev$ pip -V
pip 8.1.1 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-8.1.1-py2.7.egg (python 2.7)
```

How can I fix this? Don't I need pip to be working with Python3? Should I have done anything differently? Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to install pip3.

`sudo apt-get install python3-pip` should do it.

Then use `pip3 -V`

Comment: I get: E: Unable to locate package pip3

Comment: @coconut my bad, it's meant to be `python3-pip`

Comment: @coconut how did you find the pip3? I am having that its unable to find pip3  during the installation of pip3 though (so `sudo apt-get install python3-pip` doesn't actually work for me)

Comment: Can't find package. Doesn't work on late model ubuntu.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install python3-pip
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package python3-pip`

Unable to install pip3

Answer (score 11):

I had to go through a slightly different procedure to get this working (Ubuntu 14.04--a local machine, not AWS).  I think the difference may be that you were upgrading from 2.7 to 3.5, whereas I was updating from 3.4 to 3.5.  I installed `python3.5` through `apt-get`, then `easy_install` using `curl`, and finally `pip` using `easy_install`.

```
$ sudo apt-get install python3.5 python3.5-dev
$ sudo curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/ez_setup.py -o - | sudo python3.5
$ sudo easy_install pip
```

Success!

```
$ pip3 -V
pip 1.5.4 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (python 3.5)
```

As they say, it's turtles--or package managers--all the way down.

Answer (score 4):

It's probably `pip3 -V`.

On my system I've got `pip3`, but no `pip`.

(rant: why python is always such a mess?)

Comment: I get no such file or directory for pip3

Comment: Why is python such a mess? Too many dependencies

Answer (score 1):

The following solution worked for me:

```
sudo pip install pip --user --upgrade
sudo apt-get install python3-pip
sudo pip3 install --upgrade setuptools
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way is to use anaconda/miniconda and install the specific version. It is described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42978349/anaconda-version-with-python-3-5.

pip is then automatically included.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1274758)